# how can I launch a first time installation project?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, launch

I have an android project for first time installation.
It is related with my firm agreement pages. It comes after google agreement pages.

I tried some technics for doing it. For example,I set it as a system application. However, it is cleaned when backup and reset operation.

Does anybody know how to run it?

on AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher"
        android:label="@string/appname" >
        <activity
            android:name="xxxagreement.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="3">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

on MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    }

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(AGREEGATE_STARTED);
    sendBroadcast(i); 
    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    t.setSelected(true);
    ...
    super.onResume();
    }
```

Event Log prints:

Session 'app': Error Launching activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application doesn't have any launcher activity. Replace these lines

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

with

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```